# How to remove values after _ sign from comma separated string in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can i remove values after _ sign in sql .

Below is sample data:
        1_1,2_2,3_3,4_40

Sql Code

```
    Declare @var1 nvarchar(max)
    Set @var1 ='1_1,2_2,3_3,4_40'

    Select @var1
```

Output Required :
                 1,2,3,4

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and there is no `declare` in "SQL"). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: You can't easily do this in SQL Server using the base string functions, because there is no support for regex/wildcard replacement.

Comment: Fix your data model!  Don't store lists in strings!  Store values as columns and rows in a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I don't have Sql server 2016 .Hence I couldnot use STRING_SPLIT.
What I did is I create a User Defined Function in place of String_Split

```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplit](
    @sInputList VARCHAR(8000) -- List of delimited items
  , @sDelimiter VARCHAR(8000) = ',' -- delimiter that separates items
) RETURNS @List TABLE (item VARCHAR(8000))

BEGIN
DECLARE @sItem VARCHAR(8000)
WHILE CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0) <> 0
 BEGIN
 SELECT
  @sItem=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,1,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)-1))),
  @sInputList=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)+LEN(@sDelimiter),LEN(@sInputList))))

 IF LEN(@sItem) > 0
  INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sItem
 END

IF LEN(@sInputList) > 0
 INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sInputList -- Put the last item in
RETURN
END
```

After that I did below

```
DECLARE @var1 nvarchar(MAX);
SET @var1 = N'1_1,2_2,3_3,4_40';

SELECT LEFT(SS.[value], CHARINDEX('_', SS.[value]) - 1)
FROM [dbo].[fnSplit](@var1,',') SS;
```

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming* you are using a version of SQL Server that is fully supported, you can use `STRING_SPLIT` to split the string, and then `LEFT` and `CHARINDEX` to remove the trailing characters:

```
DECLARE @var1 nvarchar(MAX);
SET @var1 = N'1_1,2_2,3_3,4_40';

SELECT LEFT(SS.[value], CHARINDEX('_', SS.[value]) - 1)
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@var1,',') SS;
```

If the underscore might not be in the string, you can use `NULLIF` and `LEN` to avoid the errors:

```
DECLARE @var1 nvarchar(MAX);
SET @var1 = N'1_1,2_2,3_3,4_40,5';

SELECT LEFT(SS.[value], ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('_', SS.[value]),0) - 1,LEN([value])))
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@var1,',') SS;
```

If you aren't using a fully supported version of SQL Server, you'll need to use a UDF (such as `DelimitedSplit8k_LEAD`), an XML splitter or create a CLR function.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @var1 nvarchar(max)
Set @var1 ='1_1,2_2,3_3,4_40'

select STUFF( (SELECT ',' + value  as [text()]
from (
    select  
         left(value, CHARINDEX('_', value )-1) value
    from  string_split (@var1,',')
  ) s
for xml path ('')), 1, 1, NULL) as Clean_var1
```

divide and conquer, first split to columns by ',' then find the Position on '_' for each row to show right values is the digits are more than one, finaly reconstruct to show all new values as CSV using xml as text()

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function twice. First to get the values separated by commas, and second to get the numbers separated by _, returning the first number.

```
declare @var1 varchar(max) = '1_1,2_2,3_3,4_40';

select (select top 1 value from string_split(value, '_')) 
from string_split(@var1,',');
```